# Virtual Network Adapters

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am new in networking and virtualization. I really need assistance on this problem.

**I have a scenario:** there are 4 virtual machines that created through **VirtualBox on WIN7 Host**. 2 of them are centos, 1 of them is windows xp, and 1 of them is windows 2008 server. I created and installed all of them on VirtualBox on my WIN7 physical pc.

**It is expected that** only the windows 2008 server has external internet connection, and other 3 virtual machine will use it to access internet.

I searched on adapter logic (NAT, Bridged, Internal, Host-Only) but didn't get it. How should I select the adapters of VMs to do that? Thanks for help.

Comment: Why can't the host have the internet connection and all the over vm's access the internet through that interface wouldn't it be easier ?

Comment: you are right but this is my class project and expected to be work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Server config:

One interface is Internet WAN, using either NAT or Bridged with the phsycial pc ethernet interface. Let's say you choose Bridged, which means your server VM will get ip from internet router dhcp, for example 192.168.1.5.

2nd interface is Internal LAN, for example using ip address 10.10.10.1/24.

Make sure the default route is pointing to the 1st Internet Interface.

Client config:

One interface using same Internal LAN as server vm, for example ip 10.10.10.2/24.

Make sure default route is pointing to this Internal LAN interface.

Internet Gateway Router config:

Configure a static route to the Internal LAN 10.10.10.0/24 pointing to 192.168.1.5, so that router knows that this LAN is sitting behind your Physical PC.

What about NAT ?

If you choose the 1st server vm interface to use NAT, then it will get ip address from virtualbox dhcp, for example 172.16.1.2, and any traffic will be NATTed to the original physical pc ip address it got from the internet router dhcp, for example 192.168.1.2. This means when using NAT, all the VMs will appear to the internet router as if they were originated by the physical PC. In this case you do not need to add a route to your internet router.

Comment: thanks, how do i "Make sure the default route is pointing to the 1st Internet Interface" ?

Comment: run "route print" on windows command prompt or "route -n" on linux, and look for the destination of 0.0.0.0/0. or a quicker way would try to ping any website, if ping works, then you should be ok

Comment: I can ping a website or a client (10.10.10.2) from Server (192.168.1.8), but cannot ping a website from XP client. I am taking `Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.` error. [Please look at my cmd screens](http://s24.postimg.org/hr1amhilh/image.png)

Comment: the gateway on the xp client should be 10.10.10.1, i.e. pointing to the server 2nd Internal LAN Interface.

Comment: Ok, i did it but still gives same error: [SCREENSHOT](http://s11.postimg.org/mqm0r196r/asd.png)

Comment: try to ping 8.8.8.8 from client.
if it works then put 8.8.8.8 as the dns in network properties under tcpip settings

Comment: the server could ping but xp client could not.

Comment: can you ping 10.10.10.1 from the client ? also, you do not need default gateway (192.168.1.1) on Ethernet Interface 2 (10.10.10.1) on server, can you remove it ?

Comment: yes i can ping 10.10.10.1 and removed default gateway.

Comment: can you ping 192.168.1.1 ? have you added route on your internet router for the 10.10.10.0 network ?

Comment: i cannot ping 192.168.1.1 from client but server. i think i didnt add, how can i do that?

Comment: If you cannot proceed with this manual configuration, you can try running internet connection sharing on the server, as described here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324286. Internet connection sharing will automatically run DHCP, DNS, and NAT on the 2nd Internal LAN Interface of the Server, allowing the 3 clients to access the internet. And since ICS will do NAT, then you do not need to configure a route on the internet router to the internal network. Remeber to remove all internal IP Addresses and DNS on the clients before running ICS.